# Google Maps not showing inside a module of Joomla! 3x

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'm developing a website that introduce food venues and i want to add a google map inside a module to show it at the footer of website. Within the articles, the map can be shown fine, but it's not working with module side... How can i fix this problem??

Answer (score 0):

please share some more information. What is the code you use, how do you implement the module etc etc. Did you write a module on your own or are you simply adding the map to a custom html module?

A long shot since you don't provide any relevant information: try to use the 'prepare content' option on your module.